HOW CONVERT NULL SDO_GEOMETRY field with SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY
I don't know If anyone has had this problem. I'm using Datastage sw to read an Oracle table with fields SDO_GEOMETRY and write another table with these fields.
I'm using the package SDO_UTIL and particulary when I read a sdo_geometry field I use SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY utility that convert the field in LongVarchar while when I have to write the field I use SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY to convert the field again in SDO_GEOMETRY.
The problem is with the conversion utility FROM_WKTGEOMETRY when the field is a NULL SDO_GEOMETRY. In this case I get a Java Exception.
Does anyone have any solution to handle NULL SDO_GEOMETRY fields?
Thanks
Luca

Not sure I understand your question. When the input WKT column is NULL, then SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY also returns NULL. Obviously the library you are using (Datastage) must be able to handle nulls.
Consider the following table. It has two rows with a geometry object, one of them is null:
create table t1 (id number, geom sdo_geometry);
insert into t1 (id, geom) values (1, sdo_geometry(2001,4326,sdo_point_type(7.124509327482737, 43.57899482791175, null),null,null));
insert into t1 (id, geom) values (2, null);
commit;

Let's convert the geometries to WKT into another table
drop table t2 purge;
create table t2 (id number, wkt clob);
insert into t2 (id, wkt) select id, sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(geom) from t1;
commit;

This completes without any error. The NULL SDO_GEOMETRY was converted to a NULL string.
Similarly, converting the WKT strings back to SDO_GEOMETRY also results in a NULL when the string is null.
select id, sdo_util.from_wktgeometry(wkt) from t2;

The above returns NULL for the second row, as expected.

Thanks for your answer Albert.  I think I think I understand better where the problem lies
